# Determine if a number is algebraic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, mathematica, gap, python

I recall there is an algorithm involving lattices that would tell me if a given number(approximation) is an algebraic number or not, along with the exact algebraic form of the number. Is there any tool (Gap, Mathematica, python package, etc) that has an implementation of this?

I have numbers which I can approximate to any degree of accuracy I want and I would like to know if they are algebraic or not.

Comment: See the slides [How to Find Algebraic Relations?](http://algo.inria.fr/seminars/sem07-08/kauers1-slides.pdf)  An important component algorithm is the [LLL lattice basis reduction algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm)

Comment: @hardmath Briefly looking at those slides, they seem to explain finding relations among sequences - does that apply to individual constants?

Comment: You can try an [inverse symbolic calculator](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html).

Comment: @JairTaylor, no luck.

Comment: @JairTaylor:  I believe the problem here is to find an integer relation among the natural powers of a constant, thereby establishing that the constant is algebraic.  [Detecting integer relations](http://hua-zhou.github.io/teaching/biostatm280-2019spring/readings/integer.pdf) has many applications, and this one in particular.

Comment: @hardmath correct. Or any other fancy way that may  have been developed. I am open ears.

Comment: @hardmath I see, so you're looking for a recurrence relation for the sequence $x,x^2,x^3, \ldots$? That makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is an implementation in *Magma* called `MinimalPolynomial` (there is also a deprecated command `PowerRelation`). It takes as arguments the floating point approximation and a bound on the degree of the desired minimal polynomial. You can try it out using the online [Magma calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/).

Here's an example recognizing $\sqrt{2}$. First let's get its floating point approximation.

```
K<a> := QuadraticField(2);
places := InfinitePlaces(K);
nu := places[1];
approx := Evaluate(a,nu);
approx;
```

This outputs

```
1.4142135623730950488016887242096980785696718753769480731766797379907324784621070388503875343276415727350138462309122970249248360558507372126441214970999358314132226659
```

Now we compute a likely algebraic relation

```
MinimalPolynomial(approx,2);
```

which outputs

```
$.1^2 - 2
1.6958303447609538905660350145496826911258884898871672008389210380315213081007910443386606153581914903410305676643102063857015146129982219146054751103274804089508645103E-167
```

which is the polynomial $x^2 - 2$ and the error.

As others have pointed out, this command won't tell you for certain that your floating point number *is* algebraic; it simply says that there exists an algebraic number of degree $\leq d$ whose floating point approximation (under an embedding into $\mathbb{C}$) is close to the given approximation, and whose minimal polynomial is small, in some sense. The key is the [LLL algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm), which finds short vectors relative to a lattice.

Answer (score 4):

PARI has a function `algdep` which does exactly what you describe:

- https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html/Vectors__matrices__linear_algebra_and_sets.html#algdep

SageMath wraps that PARI function, also under the name `algdep`:

- https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/rings_standard/sage/arith/misc.html#sage.arith.misc.algdep

Sort of related, Ordner is a directory of real numbers:

- http://fungrim.org/ordner/

Ordner was introduced in a blog post by Fredrik Johansson:

- http://fredrikj.net/blog/2019/09/what-is-the-most-common-real-number/

Comment: Thank you for the response. I had a hard time deciding which answer to choose, but your response has been very helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I have numbers which I can approximate to any degree of accuracy I want and I would like to know if they are algebraic or not.

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, this is not decidable in finite time. For example, you might check that the first 10000000000000 digits of your number agree with $\sqrt{2}$, but you will never be able to verify that *all* of the digits agree with $\sqrt{2}$ (i.e. that the number is $\sqrt{2}$).

Comment: It is. I can verify it with other facts in my problem once I have it.

Comment: So you want an algorithm which takes a decimal approximation of a number and guesses an algebraic number which is close to that approximation? Then you'll need to be more specific about what kinds of algebraic numbers you're looking for, since the algebraic numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}$. For that matter, the decimal approximation itself is rational (hence algebraic), so that would always be the best guess if you don't narrow down your search.

Comment: lol. Sir, algebraic over the complex numbers. Also, you are not being helpful. Just state that to the best of your knowledge rationalizing of the fraction itself is the best there is. If that is the limit of your knowledge, state so and kindly wait to learn from others.

Comment: Every complex number is "algebraic over the complex numbers," so that is likely not your actual problem.  What is tractable is to take successive natural powers of your constant (known to specified accuracy) and use a basis reduction algorithm to determine either an integer relation among those powers or that none exists with integer coefficients below an effectively computable bound.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Your objections are valid, but there is a way to make the OP's question precise. For instance, if we consider the floating point approximation as a rational number, its (degree $1$) minimal polynomial will have enormous coefficients, so we would intuit that this is a "bad" guess. To use LLL, one specifies a bound on the degree of the minimal polynomial, and then looks for possible minimal polynomials that are "small" in a certain sense by turning it into the problem of finding a short vector in a lattice.

Comment: [These notes](https://share.cocalc.com/share/01d0f1844ab996da08edb1cb0ef4915b503991a1/clones/w/ant/ant.pdf?viewer=raw) give an overview of the method on p. 39.

Comment: @RichardD.James Thank you! This is very helpful and clears up my confusion about the question.

Comment: @hardmath, yes. You are correct. I misspoke.